# how to sell android applications from India?

Tags: android

i have checked from http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324 that Indian developers cannot sell paid applications on the Android market...

If i do want to sell a paid application from India, how do i go about it?
Can i advertise and upload my android applications on my website?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read any limitations in the new [Amazon app store](https://developer.amazon.com/). Maybe you want to check that out?

Comment: do you happen to know why google has blocked certain countries from selling paid applications?

Comment: The main reason seems to be payout, although I'm not sure what the specific reason is. It could be e.g. a taxation problem or something? There is this line in your link: *If you are not located in any of the countries listed above and do not own the required bank account for receiving payments, Google may not be able to pay for the sales in that account by any other means.*

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the same approach Federico from [Launcher Pro](http://www.launcherpro.com) has used. You may embedded a key in software and sell it through paypal while google market is not available in India.

Comment: could you please explain how to do it exactly. i mean i would encrypt the .apk file of my application?....

Comment: You may make a test in the first time the user try to open your app. If the user insert the right key you save the information that the app is now fully functional and continue the operation. If the user did not enter the right key, you just leave the app.

Comment: @RMAAlmeida:How do i send a key to the user ?