# Android Publisher Account on Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have made the payment of 25$ in Android Market on 2 Dec. But till now my developer account is not activated. I am unable to publish applications through it.

> Your Registration to the Android Market is still being processed. You
>   can upload applications to the Android Market but you cannot publish
>   until your registration is completed.

---

And also explain me about publishing paid apps from Android Market from india.

I have gone through following links :

[Is it true that finishing the registration to the Android Market can take up to 4 days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013783/is-it-true-that-finishing-the-registration-to-the-android-market-can-take-up-to)
[how to sell android applications from India?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390440/how-to-sell-android-applications-from-india)

I have seen this url too that includes India also to publish apps:

> In addition, Android Market users from 32 countries will be able to
>   buy apps, with the addition of Argentina, Belgium, Brazil, Czech
>   Republic, Denmark, Finland, Hong Kong, India, Ireland, Israel, Mexico,
>   Norway, Poland, Portugal, Russia, Singapore, Sweden, and Taiwan.

The above quote is from following link :

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-countries-more-sellers-more-buyers.html

Please help me on why still I am unable to set up my publisher account.

**EDIT :**

Thank you everybody for responding..I contacted android market regarding this issue using following link http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=dev_registration.

Then I received a mail from them they asked me to send order number ,screen shots , the version of OS and browsers I am using to access android market publisher account.I mailed them and within 4 hours they apologized and activated my account. :)

**UPDATE**

See this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/) now we can publish and purchase paid apps from google play .. Google added India on merchant list from 18th Oct,2012 and developers will be able to sell from android market from 25th Oct,2012 onwards

Comment: I am facing problem for getting account activated for free apps, they are asking scan of bank statement and identity proof. Did you experience same issue ?

Comment: @John Watson we need to submit these identuty proofs so as to ensure our account is not fake.Once u submit the scanned copies of these docs they will activate your account

Comment: Bank statement contains account no, balance info etc, is  it ok to black them out ?

Comment: Don't worry these information of your account will be confidential.

Comment: @Shruti, how long have you waiting for feedback from Google after your first email? And how long after your second email until account is "activated"? Thanks!

Comment: @DraganMarjanović : it took hardly 2-3 days to activate

Comment: @Shruti  You are still not able to  publish 'paid' applications from the Indian Publisher account. Are you?.

Comment: @ngen yes still i am not able to publish paid apps from india..do u know any alternative for that ?

Comment: @Shruti  Nothing that's transparent.  Most of them are fakes.  Looks like i have to get some overseas bank a/c .

Comment: So now are you publishing apps on Play? I'm from India and now looking into releasing paid apps. can you help me?

Comment: @Shruti  did you find any alternative way to publish your app ? I'm also facing the same problem. Are you up to the proceedures of opening overseas account ? please share the alternatives

Comment: @Shruti did you find any solution? could you able to publish apps now?

Comment: Yes now we can sell apps from our location also i.e. India

Comment: @Shruti do we need credit card for that? google wallet is not accepting my debit card.

Comment: yes only credit card is accepted by google wallet.

Comment: @Shruti does it supports all banks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to publish (and sell) paid Apps, you will need an active and approved Google Checkout merchant account (Google Checkout is now part of Google Wallet), and you will need to provide a valid and active bank account (checking account) to link to Google Checkout as well as Tax related information.

I have registered my company from El Salvador, Central America and then a company from USA on the Android Market and the merchant accounts where approved and I was able to publish Apps within the same day. I had zero issues. If I select to publish in All Countries, India is one of them.

If you want to publish FREE Apps you won't need a Merchant (Google Checkout) account, but there are some limitations depending on the country the Developer is or the User is, take a [look a this](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=136758)

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for replying Oscar Salguero..Please tell me that : if we want to publish free apps from India then is there any alternative to google checkout ??

Comment: ok but still its a question how should i publish paid apps ?? thanx for support Oscar..If u hav ne idea about that then please share

Comment: @Shruti:Did you find a solution to sell app from INDIA,if so can you share you solution in this thread,it will be helpful to many ppl out here.

Comment: @user1415759 : i am still searching the solution will post it here as soon as i get one ..

Comment: @Shruti hi, did u find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I can't help you with the registration, I'm not work in Google.
Try to fill out [the issue form](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/request.py?contact_type=publishing), sometimes it helps.

---

You can register as developer but you can publish only free applications (not paid).

[Supported locations for free publishers](https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=136758). India is in the list.
[Supported locations for merchants](https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324). India is not in the list.

---

On your quote:

> In addition, Android Market users from 32 countries will be able **to buy** apps, with the addition of Argentina, Belgium, Brazil, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Hong Kong, India, Ireland, Israel, Mexico, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Russia, Singapore, Sweden, and Taiwan.

You can **buy** applications in India, but you can't sell apps from India.

Comment: thanks for replying Sergey Glotov , I have filled up that form too but still no response from android market :(

Answer (score 0):

An option may be to try one of the app publishers out there like `FullyInvolvedMedia` that publish paid apps with international developers in Google Play.